# MasterPage modification in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have migrated my moss 2007 site to SharePoint 2010 machine and in all my pages I had a gradient 1px image (repeated) which was forming a thick line before the navigation bar like about us, department, Organization directory....etc

But when I migarted (db attach method) that gradient line has disappeared and instead of that i can see nothing but white background.

I tried to pull the site up with designer...went into default.master...opened up...and made changes in css file and tr property and place the gradient image. The problem is that when I go a Site Collection administrator I can see that line perfect on every page but as end user I cant see that change...whats going on? plz guide me in the direction how to inherit that change to end users also. I am new to designer and dont know in which file i need to make changes exactly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before a user can see the changes made to the masterpage, you have to publish it (and approve).